# Element item is not recognized with animation list

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to make an animation with animation list.
First when i create a new animation, Eclipse create it inside the drawable folder, and not the anim folder.
Second, when i'm typing in this xml file, it doesn't recognize anything. And I've got this error inside the log :

Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4:  tag requires a 'duration' attribute

Here the xml in question :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:oneshot="false">
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest0"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest1"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest2"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest3"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest4"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest5"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest6"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest7"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest8"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest9"
    duration="100">
</item>
<item
    drawable="@drawable/loadertest10"
    duration="100">
</item>

</animation-list>
```

And here's what i used to call it :

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dog);
    AnimationDrawable drawable = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    drawable.start();
```

---

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    image.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dog));
    AnimationDrawable drawable = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
    drawable.start();
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

In your xml, you set `drawable` and `duration`, but according to [animation resources documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html), it must be `android:drawable` and `android:duration`.